# Appcelerator Module titanium.py

Tags: module, installation, titanium, appcelerator

I'm a new Mac user and i don't anderstand the way to create the titanium.py
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Legacy_Command-Line_Interface-section-29004835_LegacyCommand-LineInterface-OSX

how can i create a bash_profil, and where must i set up those links ?
alias titanium.py="/Library/Application\ Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx//titanium.py"
alias ios_builder="/Library/Application\ Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx//iphone/builder.py"

Can anybody teach me step by step :/ ?

Thx !

Comment: and when i build and  test my module on xcode i get this error :
python: can't open file '~/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.2.3.GA/titanium.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the module configuration path to titanium.py have to add $HOME before /library and it works...

Answer (score 0):

this is my .bash_profile :

## titanium.py

alias titanium.py='~/Library/Application\ Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.1.GA/titanium.py'

## ios_builder

alias ios_builder='~/Library/Application\ Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.1.GA/iphone/builder.py'